# Botón Like con Ajax en Django

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, python-3.x, django

Estoy intentando hacer el botón like en django, pero al pulsarlo no me funciona. Muestro la arquitectura:

models.py

```
class Comentario (models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    autor = models.ForeignKey (Perfil, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    archivo = models.FileField(upload_to='media/%Y/%m/%d', null=True, blank=True)
    slug= models.SlugField(default=0)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(Perfil, related_name="likes")

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.titulo)

    @property

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug=slugify(self.titulo)
        super(Comentario, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

views.py

```
try:
    from django.utils import simplejson as json
except ImportError:
    import json

def like (request):
    if request.method=='POST':
    perfil=request.user
    slug=request.POST.get('slug', None)
    comentario=get_object_or_404(Comentario, slug=slug)

        if comentario.objects.filter(perfil__id=perfil.id).exists():
            comentario.likes.remove(perfil_id)
        else:

            comentario.likes.add(perfil_id)

    context={'likes_count':comentario.total_likes}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(context), content_type='home/json')
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^like/$', login_required(views.like), name='like')
```

.html

```
{% if objects %}
            {% for comentario in objects %}
                <tr>
                <hr><h1 class="display-4"><td>{{comentario.titulo}}</td></h1>
            </tr><br/>
            <p class="lead"><td>{{comentario.texto}}</td></p><br/>
            <cite><p class="mb-0"><td>{{comentario.autor}}</td> - <td>{{comentario.fecha_publicacion}}</td></p></cite><br/>

            {% for tag in comentario.tag.all %}
                <td>{{ tag.nombre }}</td>
            {% endfor %} 

            {% if Comentario.archivo %}
                <br/><a href="{{ detail.archivo.url}}" download >ADJUNTO: {{comentario.archivo}} </a>
            {%endif%}
<input type="button" id="like" name='{{ comentario_slug  }}' value="Like" /> 

                <script>
                $('#like').click(function(){
                     $.ajax("/home/like/",{
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "{% url 'home:like' %}",
                            data: {'slug': $(this).attr('titulo'), 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function(response) {

                            alert(' likes count is now ' + response.likes_count);
                        },
                            error: function(rs, e) {
                            alert(rs.responseText);
                            }
                        }); 
                    })
                </script>
    {% endfor %}        
    {% else %}
        <h1>No hay registros de comentarios</h1>
    {% endif %}
```

Me da error 404 ya que no reconoce ningún comentario, es decir, el problema está en la vista. Alguien me podría echar una mano?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Estás seguro que `$(this).attr('titulo')` tiene el slug del comentario? No sé si sea mejor que muestres como construyes esa parte del html y guiarte un poco más. Por otro lado, veo que luego de esa linea donde arroja el 404 tu código puede fallar

Comment: el slug existe, en la base de datos. Pero es verdad que al hacer slug=request.POST.get ('slug', None), siempre aparece None; pero en realidad en la tabla si existe. Amplio la parte del html para que lo puedas ver, aunque lo referido al boton like es el que se muestra.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que no lo estás enviando bien, fijate que en la data del ajax envias `{'slug': $(this).attr('titulo')}` y efectivamente tu input no tiene ese atributo titulo. Te recomendaría que cambiaras el atributo o agregaras otro atributo, tambien puede quedar así `{slug: '{{ comentario.slug }}'}` si no te quieres complicar mucho, pero en todo caso, te diría que revises el atributo `name` del input, porque creo que le pasas mal el slug, debe ser un `.` y no un `_` y trata de sacar el script del for, y no uses `#id` si vas a hacer eso, usa clases de css para que evites errores

Answer (score 0):

Como te dije en el comentario las correcciones que haría para que funcionara sería lo siguiente:

```
{% if objects %}
     {% for comentario in objects %}
         <tr>
            <hr><h1 class="display-4"><td>{{comentario.titulo}}</td></h1>
        </tr>
        <br/>
        <p class="lead"><td>{{comentario.texto}}</td></p><br/>
        <cite><p class="mb-0"><td>{{comentario.autor}}</td> - <td>{{comentario.fecha_publicacion}}</td></p></cite><br/>

        {% for tag in comentario.tag.all %}
            <td>{{ tag.nombre }}</td>
        {% endfor %} 

        {% if comentario.archivo %} <!--Ojo aquí, que estaba escrito con Mayúscula-->
            <br/><a href="{{ comentario.archivo.url}}" download >ADJUNTO: {{ comentario.archivo }} </a> <!--Ojo aquí, que estaba escrito detail y no comentario-->
        {% endif %}

        <input type="button" class="like" name='{{ comentario.slug  }}' value="Like" />
    {% endfor %}
    <script>
       $('.like').click(function(){
          $.ajax("/home/like/",{
             type: "POST",
             url: "{% url 'home:like' %}",
             data: {'slug': $(this).attr('name'), 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
             dataType: "json",
             success: function(response) {
                 alert(' likes count is now ' + response.likes_count);
             },
             error: function(rs, e) {
                  alert(rs.responseText);
             }
          }); 
       })
      </script>      
{% else %}
    <h1>No hay registros de comentarios</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Para que tu código funcione correctamente en la vista, debes asegurarte que tu modelo `Perfil`, sea el modelo de `Usuario` globalizado que por defecto en Django es `django.contrib.auth.models.User` Porque estás haciendo una consulta por el usuario del request (`User`) en un campo que hace consultas sobre la tabla (Perfil). No sé como tienes configurado el proyecto, pero probablemente esto genere un error

Cualquier duda comenta

Comment: gracias por la respuesta German. Ahora el error que se me presenta es el siguiente cuando hago clic en el botón like: 'attribute error at /home/like/ Manager isn't accessible via Comentario instances'. En cuanto al perfil es un modelo de usuario, que hereda user abstract, creo que eso debería de funcionar correctamente. Alguna idea con la que se pueda solucionar el error anterior? perdón por la tardanza de mi respuesta.

Comment: Esta línea te causa problemas `if comentario.objects.filter(perfil__id=perfil.id).exists():` debería ser `Comentario` con `C` mayúscula. Con el usuario, puede heredar de `UserAbastract` pero si no lo defines como el modelo de usuario predeterminado entonces obtendrás errores si no es del mismo tipo de objeto